# What to do with the results of getaddrinfo?

Tags: sockets, unix, getaddrinfo

Using `getaddrinfo` to query a host, I get a number of results:

```
struct addrinfo hints;
hints.ai_flags    = 0
hints.ai_family   = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = 0
hints.ai_addrlen  = 0;
hints.ai_addr     = NULL;
hints.ai_canonname= NULL;
hints.ai_next     = NULL;

struct addrinfo *res = NULL;
getaddrinfo("google.com", "http", &hints, &res);
```

`res` gets filled in with a list of 11 possible addresses I could use to connect to `google.com` with the given parameters:

```
1   family=2, addr.port=80, addr.address=74.125.226.98, protocol=6, socktype=1, flags=0
2   family=2, addr.port=80, addr.address=74.125.226.104, protocol=6, socktype=1, flags=0
3   family=2, addr.port=80, addr.address=74.125.226.100, protocol=6, socktype=1, flags=0
4   family=2, addr.port=80, addr.address=74.125.226.99, protocol=6, socktype=1, flags=0
5   family=2, addr.port=80, addr.address=74.125.226.96, protocol=6, socktype=1, flags=0
6   family=2, addr.port=80, addr.address=74.125.226.102, protocol=6, socktype=1, flags=0
7   family=2, addr.port=80, addr.address=74.125.226.110, protocol=6, socktype=1, flags=0
8   family=2, addr.port=80, addr.address=74.125.226.97, protocol=6, socktype=1, flags=0
9   family=2, addr.port=80, addr.address=74.125.226.105, protocol=6, socktype=1, flags=0
10  family=2, addr.port=80, addr.address=74.125.226.103, protocol=6, socktype=1, flags=0
11  family=2, addr.port=80, addr.address=74.125.226.101, protocol=6, socktype=1, flags=0
```

My question is, which do I use? Should I just always take the first one, or pick one at random? Or should I try each one in order until `connect()` succeeds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not an officially defined order, but unless you have a good reason not to: try them in order, skipping any that don't match your requirements (eg, wrong protocol).  Usually DNS servers will round-robin or somehow permute the results.  (You can probably see that if your run your test multiple times in a row or running nslookup or dig a few times on google.com.)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally the first entry is used.
DNS servers make use of this to balance the load between multiple servers, that is they return a different order each time. So you should pick the first one and continue from there until you get a successful connection.

Answer (score 0):

You should loop through them, one at a time in order, trying to `connect()` to each one until either one succeeds or you exhaust the list.